# Icon or image (PNG), which is the most performative?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm working on a project that involves displaying a map (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) and there are 34 possible types of picture pins (PNG) and I'd like to know which becomes more performative. Keep using these images or adopt the use of icons? Taking into account that the images have on average 10Kb

For those who do not know, converting to SVG can turn into an icon (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: svg icons are better  i used 100 icons in a management app! recently well duh all was perfect in performance

Comment: If you use SVG, you don't have to worry about resolution, of course. But really, with file sizes like that, you're not going to notice a performance difference either way

Comment: I disagree. It’s not the size that always matters. SVG consumes higher computational resources when rendering. But PNGs don’t consume that much.